# jQuery: get immediate next element after the current element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, traversal

I need set focus to the element that is immediate next(and in other case immediate prev ) to the current element.

For example:

```
<li>item1</li> <- prev element (get this element)
<li>item1</li><- current element
<li>item1</li> <- next element (get this element)
<li>item1</li>
```

This is what I used

```
var curr = (event.target).next();
$(curr).trigger('focus');
```

when I check the value of `curr` in firebug it shows undefined for some reason.

Answer (score 23):

Use

```
$(event.target).next()
```

to get the next sibling. You can also pass an expression to the `next` function. This will select the next sibling to match you selector:

```
$(event.target).next("p")
```

You can also use `nextAll`, which works the same way but returns all of the following sublings. [See more here](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next#expr). There is also, `prev` and `prevAll`, which are the analogues for getting the previous element(s).

Basically, you were really close, you just need to wrap `event.target` in the jQuery object, as `event.target` returns the actual element.

Answer (score 7):

Are you inside a jquery event handler? If so, why not use `$(this).next()` and/or `$(this).prev()` ?

Comment: and what about event bubbling?

Comment: Fair question. It would depend on the original selector used to hook the event, which was missing from the question. Nice answer btw, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

```
var curr = (event.target).nextSibling;
```